# How do I store a large number of regex and find the regex that has a match for a given string?

Tags: python, regex, elasticsearch, search

We generally use regex to match with strings. I want to do it the other way around. I have a large number of regex. Now, given a string, I should identify which regex had a match with the string. How do I do this?

I was considering storing all the regex in Elasticsearch and then query it using the string, but I am not able to find any documentation to see if it possible.

I could store all the regex in a DB, get the ones I want to check matches and then find matches, but is there a better way to do it?

Comment: I suspect the lack of interest in your question is because readers are one in their answers to your last sentence: No!

Comment: Yes, there's a better way to do it, see my answer below

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to do this using the [`percolator` field type](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.6/query-dsl-percolate-query.html).

You can basically index all your [`regexp` queries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.6/query-dsl-regexp-query.html) and then test which of the queries would match your document.

Create the index with a percolator field type:

```
PUT regex
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "message": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "query": {
        "type": "percolator"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Index two regular expressions, for instance:

```
PUT /regex/_doc/1
{
  "query": {
    "regexp": {
      "message": {
        "value": "big.*fox",
        "flags": "ALL",
        "case_insensitive": true
      }
    }
  }
}

PUT /regex/_doc/2
{
  "query": {
    "regexp": {
      "message": {
        "value": ".*fox",
        "flags": "ALL",
        "case_insensitive": true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then test which regular expression would match your input.

Percolating `big brown fox` would match both regular expressions above:

```
POST regex/_search
{
  "query": {
    "percolate": {
      "field": "query",
      "document": {
        "message": "big brown fox"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Percolating `big brown bear` would match none of the above:

```
POST regex/_search
{
  "query": {
    "percolate": {
      "field": "query",
      "document": {
        "message": "big brown bear"
      }
    }
  }
}
```